# How log springboot commit transaction

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, spring-boot-jpa

I create 2 methods with annotation

```
@Trasactional
```

so now how can I log the begin and commit in my transactions? I wanna to see everthing inside one transactions, when Start another insede a existing

something like this:

```
Begin1
//sqls
Begin 2

//sqls
commit 2
//sqls
Begin 3
commit 3

//sqls

//sqls
commit1
```

tks

Comment: `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in properties doesn't work as you want?

Comment: No the spring.jpa.show-sql=true only show the sql(select, insertus updates )

Answer (score 1):

Adding this property to your application.properties should do the trick

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines in app.properties helped to print logs transaction begin and commit logs

`logging.level.ROOT=INFO`

`logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG`

`logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG`